# RabbitMQ: Does anyone know how can I find the sources that describe RabbitMQ message parameters

Tags: rabbitmq

I got the contents from path: /api/queues/vhost/name and how are these parameters below?

- message_stats:
    deliver_get
- incoming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find the stats documentation:

http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/31c1d2668d39/priv/www/doc/stats.html

**EDIT****

> message_stats objects
>
> - publish   Count of messages published.
> - publish_in    Count of messages published "in" to an exchange, i.e. not taking account of routing.
> - publish_out   Count of messages published "out" of an exchange, i.e. taking account of routing.
> - confirm   Count of messages confirmed.
> - deliver    Count of messages delivered in acknowledgement mode to consumers.
> - deliver_noack  Count of messages delivered in no-acknowledgement mode to consumers.
> - get    Count of messages delivered in acknowledgement mode in response to basic.get.
> - get_noack  Count of messages delivered in no-acknowledgement mode in response to basic.get.
> - deliver_get    Sum of all four of the above.
> - redeliver  Count of subset of messages in deliver_get which had the redelivered flag set.
> - return     Count of messages returned to publisher as unroutable.
>
> **/api/queues/(vhost)/(name)**
>
> - incoming  Detailed message stats (see section above) for publishes from exchanges >into this queue.
> - deliveries    Detailed message stats for deliveries from this queue into channels.
> - consumer_details  List of consumers on this channel, with some details on each.

Comment: I would suggest just to post link to Management Plugin and notice to follow HTTP API link under Getting Started section while the direct link may be outdated with time.